# htaccess redirect all subdomains to the same directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to be able to redirect all subdomains to a folder:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$ 
RewriteRule (.+)$ "http://example.com/subdomains/%1" [L,P]
```

for example, if some visits `sub1.example.com` it will keep the URL but show `example.com/subdomains/sub1` and if the sub1 directory does not exist, it will show `example.com/404`

Is this possible?

I tried the above code but its showing me:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.
```

Wordpress says:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and at the top of my htaccess file, is:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/system/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What if you directly go to `http://example.com/subdomains/sub1/` ? Do you have a `Forbidden` error too or do you have access to it ? Anyway, your code should be working, despite the fact it's not well written. And i think it's working actually. When you have this `Forbidden`, do you see `sub1.example.com` as url ?

Comment: no that works fine with no error

Comment: Code looks also fine to me. Forbidden problem can be caused by other .htaccess settings, for example on IndexIgnore. Check where you are leaded to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your above .htaccess would externally redirect the calls, as you use a full URL as the target.

In your question you say you want to keep the hostname, so I will assume that is the requirement.

## 0) Enable rewrite engine

```
RewriteEngine On
```

## 1) Rewriting known subdomains to their directory in /subdomains

```
# Rewrite known subdomains to /subdomains/{subdomain}/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomains [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /subdomains/%1/ [L]
```

1. When we encounter a request with a subdomain,
2. and we have not rewritten it to /subdomains
3. and we have not rewritten it to /404
4. then rewrite it to /subdomains/{subdomain}/

So, if the request was

```
http://foo.example.com/hello
```

the URL in the browser would stay the same, but internally be mapped to

```
/subdomains/foo/
```

## 2) Rewriting unknown subdomains to /404

```
# Rewrite missing unknown subdomains to /404/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdomains [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /404/ [L]
```

1. When we encounter a request with a subdomain,
2. and we have already rewritten it to /subdomains
3. and we have not rewritten it to /404
4. and it is not existing as a file
5. and it is not existing as a directory
6. and it is not existing as a symlink
7. then rewrite it to /404

So, if the request was

```
http://bar.example.com/hello
```

the URL in the browser would stay the same, but internally be mapped to

```
/subdomains/bar/
```

by the first `RewriteRule` from 1).

If `/subdomains/bar/` does not exist, the second `RewriteRule` from 2) will kick in and internally map it to

```
/404/
```

## 3) Test-Environment

I actually tested all of this with exemplary code, available here: https://github.com/janpapenbrock/stackoverflow-36497197

Comment: i also have Wordpress installed - do I put these 2 parts of code above or below the wordpress code?

Comment: Do you use wordpress for these subdomains or just the main domain? If just for the main, I'd try putting it above.

Comment: its just the main domain - wordpress runs only on the main domain. ive tried putting it above and it works, but stops the main domain (wordpress) from working and if i put it below, wordpress works but none of the subdomains do

Comment: Do you call your main domain with www.?

Comment: i guess visitors will call it both with and without

Comment: And what did you set in WordPress? Anyway, better put in an exception for that subdomain into the above rules.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$

Comment: check my update - so i have admin. going to a custom location and the wordpress code in there. and as i said, i want all other subdomains to map to /subdomains/{subdomain} and if not found to map to /404.php

Comment: Not really. Maybe post your directory structure and a list of which URL directs where.

Comment: Ok so in public_html I have my Wordpress installation. Then also in public_html there is directories: admin and subdomains

Comment: Then admin. Maps to admin/system and all other subdomains should point to subdomains/{subdomains}

Comment: can you advise further on this as its still not working

Comment: Well, the original question was solved IMHO. The additional requirements change the solution substantially. Maybe you can create a separate question and revert the changes here, so we can keep this solved and simple.

Comment: ive created another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745680/htaccess-will-not-rewrite-subdomains

Answer (score 3):

I'd say you are experiencing a permission issue. I guess your Apache server runs as `apache` user. Use `chmod` to give `apache` access to this path.