# htaccess will not rewrite subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this code in my `htaccess` file stored in the root:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin.mydom.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/system/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.mydom\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /subdomains/%1/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mydom.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydom.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The file should ensure the following is done on the site:

`admin.` subdomain is mapped to `/admin/system`

map all subdomains to `/subdomains/{subdomain}`

redirect any domain other than `mydom.com` to `mydom.com`

and then the standard wordpress htaccess

Its working fine apart from the subdomain part, all subdomains are being redirected back to the main domain (mydom.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydom.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# redirect sub.dom2.com to sub.mydom.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.(?!mydom\.)[^.]+\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.mydom.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin\.mydom\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^admin/system/ admin/system%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.mydom\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subdomains/ subdomains/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(subdomains/|admin/|index\.php$) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: that seems to be working apart from the main domain (with and without www.) its trying to go to `/subdomains/www`

Comment: ah yes thats working now - how about adding in if you visit `sub.dom2.com` it will forward to `sub.dom.com`so all subdomains will will forward to the main domain

Comment: ok, so there are multiple domains we have pointing to this server. thats why everything it redirected to `www.dom.com` if that it not already the URL. if someone visits `dom2.com` it will redirect them to `dom.com` but how can i add the same for the subdomains - if someone visits `sub.dom2.com` it will currently redirect to `www.dom.com` but can it redirect to the same subdomain?

Comment: just updated that - its now not mapping the subdomains to the subdomains directory, its just showing the main website

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110131/discussion-between-anubhava-and-charlie).

Comment: hello - i have one last thing on this if you can answer quickly?

Comment: Yes, sure let me know what is your question

Comment: when i visit the main domain without `www.` it is redirecting. its adding the main domain as a subdomain

Comment: It will be easier to resolve this in chat window. Use above chat link or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess?sort=newest&pageSize=50

Answer (score 2):

You can try to change the beginning:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin\.mydom\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^admin/system/ /admin/system%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydom\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.mydom\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subdomains/%1 /subdomains/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mydom.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydom.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

it avoids multiple rewrites
But I do not know if it was the source of your problem

Comment: if i visit the www. thats showing an internal server error

Comment: yep, stopped the error but now when i visit a subdomain its showing me the same as the main domain and not the contents within the subdomains' directory

Comment: the content with www is the same as the main domain ?

Comment: with and without www. is showing the main domain which is fine. all subdomains should be mapped to `/subdomains/{subdomain}` but instead they are all showing the main domain

Comment: yes thats working fine as its access the directory directly but when going to `sub.mydom.com` it should map to `www.mydom.com/subdomains/sub` but instead its showing the main domain `(www.mydom.com)`

Comment: I understood that. I wonder if this is not a configuration problem which is not related to this htaccess

Comment: ok - main domain working but all subdomains show internal server error

Comment: Look in the logs the explanation of the error. But otherwise I have no other idea. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.mydom.com$
RewriteRule ^((?!admin/system).*)$ /admin/system/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+)\.mydom\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /subdomains/%1/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mydom.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydom.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Clear your browser's cache before testing this.

Comment: @Charlie Do you have any other rules in htacces?

Comment: check the OP for other rules

Comment: @Charlie If this is your full htaccess, then both answers posted here should work.

Comment: unfortunately not :(