# How to wildcard subdomain redirect subdomain name directory without changing URL

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, wildcard

How to redirect any wildcard domain from htaccess to that wildcard name directory.

For Extample:

https://customer.domainname.com/login.php => https://www.domainname.com/customer/login.php

https://admin.domainname.com/login.php => https://www.domainname.com/admin/login.php

https://faq.domainname.com => https://www.domainname.com/faq
.
.
.
Any wildcard domain redirects without browser URL change.
We used the code below, but it doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.domainname\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step is getting the DNS to work the way you expect. You will need a DNS provider that supports wildcard subdomains: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record

After the DNS is configured to send all undefined subdomains to your host, look here for options setting up the .htaccess: [htaccess redirect all subdomains to the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497197/htaccess-redirect-all-subdomains-to-the-same-directory)